# Generate fixed length unique string from 2

Tags: javascript, typescript, string, numbers, generator

I have two numbers `919572562474827787` and `359678229096955904`

I need to generate a unique string with fixed length so I can regenerate it again and get the same value.
How can I do it?

Comment: @LucaKiebel With .encode() can i set the length of the output string?

Comment: You say those are "numbers", but I hope they're being stored as bigints or strings, because they're too big to be stored as integers in JavaScript.

Comment: @jcalz, yes, they stored as strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with built-in functions from [`SubtleCrypto`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/digest).

This function will return a cryptographically secure SHA-256 hash of the numbers. This will work independent of the system you run this with, and return the same output for the same input.

```js
const hash = async (number1, number2) => btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(await crypto.subtle.digest("SHA-256", new TextEncoder().encode(number1+number2)))))

hash("919572562474827787","359678229096955904").then(console.log)
// => XG14mUazSAw/JpETwqHsijVgVdjdCOnczr5MMBU6qBc=
```